# SQL: does prepending a field name with a subquery identifier enforce the subquery to be evaluated first?

Tags: sql, relational-database

My question is not about understanding what happens (possibly in different implementations) in the following queries. 
It is instead about understanding whether SQL standard defines what the correct behaviour should be.

A simple table with negative and positive integers:

```
CREATE TABLE x (n INTEGER);

INSERT INTO x VALUES (-2);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (2);
```

Take this query first:

```
select n
from x 
where n <> 0 
and   1/n = 1;
```

Obviously, the smart evaluation order that one would expect is exactly as it is written in the query, to avoid computing 1/0, which would cause an error.

However, SQL is a declarative query language, and as already explored in several questions the order of where clauses does not matter, so they could be evaluated in any order, which means a division by 0 error could happen and would be ok. That is clear.

Now the second example:

```
select nonzero.n
from (select n from x where n <> 0) as nonzero
where 1/nonzero.n = 1;
```

This is logically the same in terms of where clauses on table `x`, but they are organised differently. 
This time I'm defining a relation that cannot have 0s. The main query explicitly evaluates `1/nonzero.n`, so I would intuitively expect the engine to enforce an evaluation order here, and not see any division by 0.

Notice that this is not the only evaluation option that I have seen in practice. Some SQL engines would first flatten the second query back to the first one.

Regardless of what different implementations do, my question is: does SQL standard enforce in any way that when I write `nonzero.n` then `n` is really taken from relation `nonzero` and not from `x`, which obviously are not equivalent?
If so, would you know any pointer to where this is expressed formally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard does not specify what to do.  It is quite weak on error processing.

More importantly, the standard is quite explicit that the order of evaluation of expressions and components of a query are not enforced -- there is no ordering for subqueries or the expressions in a `select`.  The query as a whole describes the result set -- not step-by-step instructions for creating it.

This is quite intentional.  The folks who write the standard know that the execution plan is typically a directed acyclic graph (DAG) that has nothing to do with the original query (except for implementing it!).

Note that there are cases where `1/0` is not evaluated at all.  Some databases access:

```
where exists (select 1 / 0
              from t
              where . . .
             )
```

Exists only cares whether rows are returned, not what the values are on those rows.

Comment: Granted. But from a language semantics point of view, doesn't `1/nonzero.n` imply that `n` should be taken from a relation that cannot have 0s (because it was defined as such)? Wouldn't ignoring this violate my (declarative) query? I'm not expecting to say _how_ to do something, but I'm expecting that the _what_ I requested is respected.

Comment: @cornuz . . . The standard is really weak on error processing.  I happen to agree with you.  But databases seem to interpret it differently.  And from what I remember of the details of the standard, both are consistent.